# Why isn't Amazon using a NONCE for REST Authentication?

Tags: rest, hmac, nonce

When you look at Amazons [RESTAuthentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) you can see that it doesn't use a nonce:

```
Authorization = "AWS" + " " + AWSAccessKeyId + ":" + Signature;

Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) );

StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Date + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;

CanonicalizedResource = [ "/" + Bucket ] +
    <HTTP-Request-URI, from the protocol name up to the query string> +
    [ subresource, if present. For example "?acl", "?location", "?logging", or "?torrent"];

CanonicalizedAmzHeaders = <described below>
```

Shouldn't this include a nonce? Do they guard against replay attacks in another way? How?

Comment: technically the StringToSign include a date, which, whilst not random, is a nonce.  Maybe there's smarts behind the scenes to check timestamps/dates.

Comment: @ColinCassidy How is a date a nonce? It can be used multiple times in a time window.

Comment: Their documentation states:
"the client timestamp included with an authenticated request must be within 15 minutes of the Amazon S3 system time when the request is received. If not, the request will fail with the RequestTimeTooSkewed error code. The intention of these restrictions is to limit the possibility that intercepted requests could be replayed by an adversary. For stronger protection against eavesdropping, use the HTTPS transport for authenticated requests."

Maybe they feel that timestamps and HTTPS is sufficient to cover that threat

Comment: Indeed, HTTPS alone is supposed to be sufficient.

Comment: The problem with requiring a nonce is you then have to store it to do replay checking agains the list of previously seen nonces. What they do require is the timestamp and then limit its usability to a specific window. This provides replay protection outside of that window and doesn't require storage.

Answer (score 2):

Usage of a nonce makes the design complicated. The s3 server will have to send a nonce and the client will have to maintain a session or hold the nonce value. The absence of nonce definitely leads to replay attack as you mentioned and that is the primary reason for all direct URL access vulnerabilities which exist in applications which uses S3 storage. Amazon thinks that limiting the attack surface using a time stamp reduces the risk to an acceptable level. For example if the request time-stamp is not within a set window (5-15 mins) it is considered invalid.